# Deciding the color variant of the element

Tags: javascript, web, colors

I have simple task:
I have N elements, each element is supposed to be darker or lighter shade of the color, depending on the index of the element.

So for example with the element `[element1,element2,elemen3...]` and color blue, I want the element to be the darkest shade of the blue, and each next element to be a little lighter shade of the blue. so `element1` would be the darkest shade of the blue and `elementN` would be the lightest shade of blue.

Now I know (for example), that the RGB representation of the blue is (0,0,255). However, reducing the 'G' part does not make the shade of the blue lighter.

I tried to do simple:

var data = [...];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
var color = 255 - i;
var rgb = "rgb(0,0," + color " + );
.....
}

What is the trick for deciding shade of the color this way? Thanks for help!

Comment: Your question was closed without getting to your question. Think about coloring your wall. You were trying to get a brighter blue by adding more of the same blue. That won't help. You need to add some white in there to get it brighter. I'll link you to something you may have found yourself learning in school before https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color and how that works in RGB, the digital kind itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model. Mind the first paragraph on the later. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Nathan gonna check it out, thanks!